# I get Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier on VSCODE (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

While im trying to create a server and run on my browser i get an error like this:

I get Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier

My code is on below:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const http = require("http");

 const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    res.end("Hello from the server!");

});

server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log("listening to requests on port 8000");
})
```

I work on Visual Studio Code. I just wrote on the terminal

> node 
>   node index.js

Comment: there is no error, clean cache.. hard reload. command + r

Comment: thank you so much it worked!

Comment: hahaha! hope u can give me point :-D

Comment: i m a new here so cant do it yet. But in the future if a review this post i ll come back and give u a point definetly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct, the command to run a .js file by NodeJS from the command line is `node jsFileName.js`, I see two `"node"` words in your command?!

Comment: i installed reload extension to my Visual Code Studio (windows), it worked. I clicked it and it worked! Thank you!